# foreign key constraint stopping me inserting into table

Tags: mysql, insert, constraints

I have 3 tables: **photos**, **products_types** & **prints**.

The idea is that there you can combine **photos** and **product_types** in a number of ways to create **prints** (of which there can be many duplicates, but with a unique id).

Then there is a 4th table: **stock_details**, which keeps track of **prints** that are in **shops** and **prints** that are not.

I added a foreign key constraint to **prints**, so that when I delete **prints**, the **print** is deleted from **stock_details**.

And then I found that when I want to create a **print**, the query fails because no corresponding **print** is created in **stock_details**.

> how can i do an insert constraint/trigger that will create a
>   corresponding entry in the **stock_details** table?

Or

> Alternatively, what are better ways of dealing with this? I feel like
>   there shouldn't need to be two records created.

Comment: Why your photo depends on stock not the opposite?

Comment: yes i see now that is a problem, thanks

Comment: Should foreign key constraints only be added on the table where the field is a primary key?

Comment: can you elaborate on that a little bit? if i have a user who has a lot of tweets, I would want to be able to delete those tweets irrespective of the user (therefore no constraint, just a foreign key). I would put the constraint on the user table so that if the user was deleted all the users tweets would be deleted. is this not the case? I'm not sure I'm understanding how constraints are enforced